# Displaying filtered data in React

Tags: reactjs, api, filtering, use-state

Ok, so I recently had a take-home coding challenge which I failed. One of the reasons was I couldn't figure out how to implement filtering in React using checkboxes. So I resorted to doing the filtering using CSS, but they wanted me to do using react state.

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);//api call data saved here
  const [publisher, setPublisher] = useState({// this state checks which checkboxes are selected or not
    Nin: false,
    MS: false,
    SN: false
  });
```

So for the assignment, I had to make an API call, which would give me more than 1000 items in the response. I had to filter that object to only have 3 types of products saved up in State, which I did with no problem.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchJsonp("apicall", {
      jsonpCallback: "jsonp"
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) =>
        setData(
          json.filter(
            (x) =>
              x["Publisher"] === "Nintendo" ||
              x["Publisher"] === "Sony" ||
              x["Publisher"] === "Microsoft"
          )
        )
      )
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

The issue was that once the Cards were showing on the screen, which was absorbing data from the local state. The user had the option to filter via a checkbox to only see the type of products from Nintendo, Microsoft, or Sony, or all games would show if no checkbox was selected.

So my question is how would one go about implementing this feature in react?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a filter function in your render. I'm assuming for the cards you were using `map` so just do something like

```
return (
  <>
    {data.filter((item)=>{
      const {Nin, MS, SN} = publisher;
      if(!Nin && !MS && !SN){ //return all if no boxes checked
        return true;
      }
      else{
        return (Nin && item.publisher === 'Ninetndo') || 
          (SN && item.publisher === 'Sony') || 
          (MS && item.publisher === 'Microsoft')
      }
    }).map((x) => <Card />)}
  </>
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly what U was trying to do.